# Ccamera screenshot from a preview every second with cameraX in Jetpack Compose

Tags: concurrency, android-jetpack-compose, screenshot, kotlin-coroutines, android-camerax

I am using cameraX preview to capture the front camera for about 20 secs. Would like to capture screenshot every second via preview.bitmap and store them as png files in a folder so that I can later use ffmpeg and create a short video or gif with ffmpeg.
The idea I tried was to put main loop in a composable's Launched Effect block, to repeat call to function every sec, like this:

```
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    while (true) {
            delay(1000)
            if (isTimerRunning) {
                Log.d("MP20", "in coroutine scope:${a.value}")
                val bitmap = previewView.bitmap

                if (bitmap != null && isTimerRunning == true) {
                    myViewModel.saveBitmapToPosesFolder(bitmap, context = context, ext = a.value.toInt())
                    a.value = a.value.plus(1)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

In view model I have a function I was hoping to run every second no matter how long it needs to create a file - i Put it in viewModelScope.launch:

```
fun saveBitmapToPosesFolder(bitmap: Bitmap, context: Context, ext: Int) =
viewModelScope.launch {
    Log.d("MP20", "saveBitmapToPosesFolder and ext is:$ext")
    //val bitmap = previewView?.bitmap
    val dirPath = context.filesDir.absolutePath
    val fName = "${dirPath}/poses/live${ext}.png"
    if (bitmap != null) {
        File(fName).writeBitmap(bitmap, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 65)
    }
}
```

I also tried another way with coroutines and suspend functions, but no matter what I do, I can not achieve what I want. Read/write operation of bitmap to a file always takes cca 2 secs and a loop in LaunchedEffects always waits for the writeBitmap to finish, as oppose to shoot a new bitmap every sec and then write that to a file on another (non blockin thread).

This is writeBitmap func:

```
fun File.writeBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, format: Bitmap.CompressFormat, quality: Int) {
outputStream().use { out ->
    bitmap.compress(format, quality, out)
    out.flush()
}
```

}

Have tried with making it suspend, but without success so far

Comment: Can you try attaching Dispatcher to the coroutine, like `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {...}`. Because as of now all of them are running on main thread, as far as I can speculate from the code povided.

Comment: Thank you @Himanshu. This works. I wonder why it was not working from suspend function with Dispatyhers attached - that function was not in viewModel, could be that . . Tks mister.